# jQuery: autosubmit on enter vs. browser autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, autocomplete, submit

I use this JavaScript code to submit the nearest button if the user presses the "enter"-key in a form:

```
jQuery.fn.installDefaultButton = function()
{
$('form input, form select').live('keypress', function(e)
{
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13))
    {
        if ($(this).closest('form').find('button').size() <= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        var defaultButton = $(this).closest('form').find('button:first');
        defaultButton.click();
        $(this).blur();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
});
return this;
```

};

If browser autocomplete is enabled and the user selected a proposed value by pressing the "enter"-key the form is submitted. But this is not the desired behavior. The submit should not be performed in that case. Is there any way to prevent that?

edit:
Here a little example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1 /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="action.do">
        <input name="input1"/>
        <input name="input2"/>
        <button type="submit" name="button_action1" class="button">Button 1</button>
        <input name="input3"/>
        <input name="input4"/>
        <button type="submit" name="button_action2" class="button">Button 2</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thats a long way to do it. You dont need to find the button and click it you can find the form and do .submit() no need to force a click on the button. Also try a change event opposed to key press?

Comment: Just out of interest before I attempt to answer your question why is a browsers auto implementation of pressing enter to submit not acceptable? And just as a quick note replace your find button code with $(this).closest('form').submit();

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I use the mechanism to find the next button because, the right button must be submitted, if I have more than one button on a form. I need the name of the button to handle specific processing. The browser auto handling does not work very weel with IE, because this browser does not send the nearest button with the request I need for processing.

Comment: Ok, I see what your trying to do its not very nice id suggest finding another way to send the info you need but ill write a quick fix for you.

Comment: Please support the community by selected a final answer, green tick, if the available answers answered your question

Answer (score 1):

Ive not had a chance to try this out but it should work for you.

```
$("form").live('change', function(e) {
   $(this).data('changed', true); 
});

$('form input, form select').live('keypress', function(e)
{
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    if (((e.which && e.which == 13 || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) && form.data('changed') == true)
    {
         if ($(this).closest('form').find('button').size() <= 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var defaultButton = form.find('button:first');
        defaultButton.click();
        $(this).blur();
        console.log("Submitted!");
        form.data('changed', false);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

The change event is not triggered by you pressing enter on a autocomplete (Or not at least in my previous experience) so when there is an actual valid change you'll want to send it. There may be a case where when you click into a cell that you want to set the form data "changed" to true but you'll need to experiment and see if you get the behavior you expect.

Edit:

To show you what i meant

```
$("form").live('focus', function(e) {
   $(this).data('changed', true); 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the 'enter' on browser autocomplete does not trigger the change event. You have to leave the the autocompleted field i.e. with tab first, after that submit with enter works. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, like i mentioned perhaps try binding a similar thing to focus. Ill attach another example onto my answer. Sorry I cant really test it, feel free to set up a jsbin/jsfiddle if you would like a bit more help with it. (And please, if i do end up solving this for you accept the answer :))

Comment: Its hard to know exactly what your doing without an example that would definetely help but again, you might need to tag changed as false on focus out.

Comment: Focus will not work, because data is true if I already enter the first letter for autocompletion. I think their is no real solution for the problem, because there is no way to get JavaScript access for autocomplete events. Your example will only work, if I only use autocompletion for one field. It will automatically submit the second one on enter. Yet, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah its a tricky thing to try to handle manually, there is 1 more approach that you could do though, if your intrested. It might actually work, thinking about it. Up to you.

Comment: Yeah, I happy to hear your thoughts. I will provide you a small example on weekend.

Comment: What data do you actually need from the button your looking for?

Comment: I need the button name. I will add a example to my original post.

Comment: Ill take a look at this for you as soon as I can.